# What is the other version of defining the stream operator called?

Tags: c++

Everything I can find on google deals with adding stream compatibility to your classes so that you can go

```
std::cout << myClassInstance;
```

but I'm not interested in that, what I want to do is

```
myClassInstance << "stuff here";
```

What is that operation called?

Comment: Well, depends on what it does. You can implement anything, e.g. multiplication, with that syntax if you want to.

Comment: it takes stuff through the << like any other stream and then I do things with said stuff, presumably in a function

Comment: And what is that *"stuff"*?

Comment: what does it matter? that is not the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overload the `<<` operator? Which is technically a bit shift operator, but it's probably used more often as a stream operator.

*<sub>Not that it makes any sense IMHO. I guess it looks nice, but I think the function call operator would have been more logical.</sub>*

```
template <typename T>
MyClassType& MyClassType::operator<<(const T& rhs)
{
    do_something_vague_and_unclear_because_there_is_no_MCVE(rhs);
    return *this;
}
```

You'll most likely have to use different overloads for specific parameter types, rather than a template function.

```
MyClassType& MyClassType::operator<<(const std::string& str)
{
    //...
}

MyClassType myClassInstance;
myClassInstance << "Hello, world!";
```